# R consider the value of variable as parameter

Tags: r

I have following function

```r
func <- function(data, variable) {
  ggplot(data = data, aes(x = as.factor(variable))) +
    geom_bar()
}

data <- mtcars
func(data, "mpg")
```

I don't know how to make my function to understand that it must take the value of `variable` as parameter in `ggplot`.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lapply with boxplots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585360/lapply-with-boxplots-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)
```

1) Pass variable as quoted :

```
func <- function(data, variable){
  ggplot(data= data, aes(x = factor(!!sym(variable)))) +  geom_bar()
}

func(mtcars, 'mpg')
```

2) Pass variable unquoted

```
func <- function(data, variable){
  ggplot(data= data, aes(x = factor({{variable}}))) +  geom_bar()
}

func(mtcars, mpg)
```

[image]

Comment: See more information here and here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9v9-EpTuwk0

https://www.njtierney.com/post/2019/07/06/jq-bare-vars/

Comment: thanks!!!  what would I do if I want to select this column in this function? like ``` data${{variable}} <- data${{variable}}*10 ```

Comment: Don't use `$` in functions. You can directly do : `data[[variable]] <- data[[variable]] * 10`. Provided `variable` is `"mpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to pass either quoted or unquoted, we can use `ensym`

```
library(ggplot2)
func <- function(data, variable){
   ggplot(data= data, aes(x = factor(!!ensym(variable)))) + 
          geom_bar()
 }

func(mtcars, 'mpg')
func(mtcars, mpg)
```